# jquery not compatible with mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, compatibility

i have a basic responsive menu code of jquery, which is working fine on decreasing browser width on desktop, but not working on mobile itself, for which it was made. code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480){

        $('nav').addClass("wrapper");

        $('.menuresp').click(function(){

            $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();

        });

    }

    else{
    $('nav').removeClass("wrapper");
    }



});
```

here is the nav html:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menuresp"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">sale</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    </ul><!-- resp menu -->

    <div class="cb"></div>
</nav>
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUySL/

Also ,i think that jquery is not working at all on mobile, as i have another small slideToggle script not working. Please tell where I am wrong. I tested on micormax canvas2 mobile on its default browser.

Comment: Make sure you declare the script tag on head in proper order..try $(window).width() instead of document.documentElement.clientwidth

Comment: Koushik, please explain the 'proper order'

Comment: script jquery,jquery mobile , and you extra plugin script .... it seems your code working fine... which plugin u using phoneGap?

Comment: no plugin using. i am not using jquery mobile also. just jquery library and script that i have shown